# Second Derivative Test in Banach Spaces

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, maxima-minima, nonlinear-analysis, frechet-derivative

According to $[$Exercise $12.8$, $1]$ we have the following version of the Second Derivative Test:

**Theorem.** Let $E=(E,\|\cdot \|)$ be a Banach space, let $D$ be a subset of $E$ and suppose $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $2$ times continuously differentiable at a point $x \in D$. If $f'(x)=0$ and the bilinear form $f''(x)$ is positive definite that is $[f''(x)(v)](v)>0$ for every nonzero $v \in E$, then $f$ attains a local mininum at $x \in D$ that is there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that if $\|y-x\|<\varepsilon$, then $f(x)<f(y)$.

Here, the differentiability is in the Fréchet sense, where $f'(x):E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the first Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $x$ and $f''(x)$ stands the second Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $x$ so that for each $v \in E$, $f''(x)v \in \mathcal{L}(E, \mathbb{R})$ . Moreover, $f$ be $2$ times continuously differentiable in $x$ means that the function $y \mapsto f'(y)$ is continuously differentiable in $x$ that is $y \mapsto f'(y)$ is differentiable at each point in a neighborhood of $x$ and $y \mapsto f'(y)$ is continuous at $x$.

**Question.** The theorem above is true? If is true, how to prove?

I've seen similar results $($for instance in $[2])$. However, in general such results require that the domain $D$ of the functional be either open/convex $($for instance, a open ball in $E)$. In this case, we have that the domain of the functional is just a subset of $E$. So I seriously doubt whether such a result remains valid in this subset context. In $[1]$ the author gives a hint to prove the theorem: use the Mean Value Theorem $([$Theorem $12.7$, $1])$ twice to show that $f(y)-f(x)>0$ for all $y \in E$ in a sufficiently small ball around $x$. But even then I still haven't been able to prove such a result. Is it possible to prove it this way?

$[1]$ Baggett, L. *Functional analysis. A primer*. Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York, $1992$.

$[2]$ Deimling, K., *Nonlinear functional analysis*. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, $1985$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the specific subset $D$ you are working with?

Comment: @Overflowian Has the form $D:=\{ v \in E \; ; \; g(v)=\lambda \}$ for some functional $g:E \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: is $g:E\to \mathbb R$ smooth? Is possible that the differential of $g$ at points $x\in D$ vanish? (in other words is $\lambda $ a regular value of $g$?)

Comment: @Overflowian Yes, $g$ is smooth. The second question: possibly no.

Comment: @Overflowian the result stated by you may be useful to me. Can you point me to some reference that contains this result?

Comment: More concisely, if $\lambda$ is a regular value of $g$ then $D = g^{-1}(\lambda)$ is a smooth Hilbert manifold and you can apply what I wrote in my answer, for more details see Palais paper. 
If however $D$ has singularities i.e. the differential of $g$ vanishes at some point of $D$, then you have to understand the singularity. See for a finite-dimensional example my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501232/no-lagranges-multiplier-in-constraint-optimization-problem/2501344#2501344

Answer (score 7):

The theorem is not true.

Here is a counterexample: Take $E=l^2$, $D=E$, and
$$
f(x) = \sum_k \frac1k x_k^2 -x_k^3.
$$
Then
$$
f'(x)v = \sum_k (\frac2k x_k -3x_k^2)v_k,
$$
$$
f''(x)(v,v) = \sum_k (\frac2k  -6x_k)v_k^2,
$$
hence $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)(v,v)>0$ for all $v\ne 0$. One can check that these derivatives are Frechet derivatives and continuous.

Define $y_n := \frac 2n e_n$, where $e_n$ is the standard unit vector.
Then $y_n \to 0$, $f(y_n) = -4/n^3$, and $x=0$ is not a local minimum of $f$.

The problem is that $f''(0)(e_n,e_n) = \frac2n$, which gets arbitrarily small. A sufficient condition would be the existence of $\delta>0$ such that
$$
f''(x)(v,v) \ge \delta \|v\|^2 \quad\forall v.
$$
In finite-dimensional spaces this follows from the $f''(x)(v,v)>0$ for all $v\ne0$ due to compactness of the unit ball.

Comment: Great answer! What is missing from the hypothesis for the theorem of $[1]$ to be true?

Comment: What I wrote: the condition involving $\delta$.

Comment: Do you know some references which contains some (correct) result similar to presented in $[1]$ for general subsets $D$?

Comment: The monograph of Bonnans & Shapiro is one reference.

Answer (score 2):

daw gave a nice answer/counterexample.
I want to add a more geometric interpretation.

There is a version of Morse Lemma in the Hilbert setting, which asserts that  if $x_0$ is a *non-degenerate* critical point of $f\in C^3(E,\mathbb R)$ i.e.  $f''(x_0)$ induces an
isomorphism $v\in E\mapsto f''(x_0)(v,\cdot)\in E^*$  with the dual of $E$ then  up to a smooth change of coordinates defined in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, $f$  takes the form
$$f(v) = f(x_0) + \frac 1 2 \vert\vert P_+ v \vert\vert^2 - \frac 1 2 \vert\vert P_- v \vert \vert^2$$
where $P_+, P_- : E\to E$ are orthogonal projectors to the positive/negative eigenspace of $f''(x_0)$.

Therefore $f$ becomes locally a quadratic functional.

From this we see that if $f''(x_0)$ is also positive definite (and $x_0$ is non-degenerate as above) then $P_- =0$ thus locally $f(v) = f(x_0) + \frac 1 2 \vert\vert P_+ v \vert\vert^2$
and we have a minimum at $x_0$.

However positive definiteness is not enough to have non-degeneracy if $E$ is infinite dimensional.
A sufficient condition that can be added is to require that  $\vert \vert f''(x_0)(v,\cdot)\vert \vert\geq C \vert \vert v \vert \vert$ for some $C>0$
this indeed implies that $v\mapsto f''(x_0)(v,\cdot):E\to E^*$ has closed range and now positive definiteness is enough to conclude that is also invertible (continuously).

This can be found in
*Palais, Morse theory on Hilbert manifolds,  Topology, Vol.2  pp. 299-340. 1963.*

Comment: Where can I find similar results of $[1]$? Since my goal is to minimize a functional $f$ whose domain is a subset under a constraint.

Comment: @Guilherme The Morse Lemma I talked about works not just for $E$ an Hilbert space but even when $E$ is a manifold modelled on an Hilbert space.
Depending on your constraint this might be the case.

Comment: Where can I found the Morse Lemma in the Hilbert space context? Do you know some book?

Comment: @Guilherme it's in a paper by Palais see my answer above.

Comment: I read the Morse Lemma link and your answer, but I can't see how it can be useful in showing that a critical point is actually a minimizer.

Comment: @Guilherme I kindly suggest you to read my answer above.